# How get data from database according to hour?

Tags: sql

I want to extract data from db according storing time. For example I have to show data per hour so i get data from current time to past one hour???

Thanks

Comment: Have a `datetime` field in your table ... `ORDER BY that_field DESC` ... DONE!

Comment: More information is needed before this can be answered - most importantly, the database platform you are using.  You will need to use a non standard database function to get the current date and time and this differs from platform to platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use > DATEADD(hh,-1, GETDATE()) in where condtion.

it will give last one hour data